# jquery load to parent of iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a form that submits to an iframe. That frame processes a coldfusion page (based on form input, attachments can be added to an item in Oracle.) There is a div, with class testing, that displays the currently attached documents on the item. What I need to do is, if the user added attachments and then submitted the form, reload the 'testing' div with the proper attachments. This is what I've tried that isn't working for me:

```
<!--- This is in my coldfusion processing page, after the form submit --->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.testing', parent.document).load('itemAttachments.cfm?_cf_nodebug=true&itemID=' + selectedItem, function(){
        alert();
    });
});
```

I don't even get the alert, so I know that somehow this syntax is wrong. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Or, is there another way to do this? Thanks.

**EDIT**

If this is confusing:

**User loads initial form that displays item properties including documents attached >>
user has option to attach new documents >> items are attached via 'attach' button, but not stored in the database or server until actual form submit >> on form submit, if new documents were attached, it should reload the 'testing' div (which is the div that display the attached documents) with the new correct information (ie: it should display the documents that the user just added)**

Comment: Little confused, do you want some stuff displayed (via $.load()) in the div with class 'testing'?

Comment: Do you see the get request being fired in Firebug or similar?

Comment: @hsalama I don't have firefox. My developer tools are very limited.

Comment: If you access itemAttachments.cfm?_cf_nodebug=true&itemID=someItemId directly in a browser, do you get any errors?

Comment: @hsalama No errors, it displays correctly with the right information. BTW, itemAttachments.cfm is also an include in my initial item form, and that loads right as well. So I know it is not that. Also, everything on the processing page works as it is supposed to, except this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15378/discussion-between-hsalama-and-jeff-fabiny)

Comment: @hsalama Internet access is very restricted where I am lol, can't chat at the moment.

Comment: was asking, The code you have, is that enclosed in a click event or something?

Comment: Can you post the code on jsfiddle or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct scope was window.parent.document.